# Big-O analysis for a loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, big-o

I've got to analyze this loop, among others, and determine its running time using Big-O notation.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 4 )
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        for ( int k = 1; k < j*j; k *= 2 )`
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 4 ) = n
```

---

```
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) = n
```

---

```
for ( int k = 1; k < j*j; k *= 2 ) = log^2 n
```

Now the problem I'm coming to is the final running time of the loop. My best guess is O(n^2), however I am uncertain if this correct. Can anyone help?

Edit: sorry about the Oh -> O thing. My textbook uses "Big-Oh"

Comment: Since you execute all inner loops for each iteration of the outer loops it would be a simple multiplication, i.e. O(n * n *  log(n) ). (Didn't check your individual results though).

Comment: I think the third loop isn't `log^2 n`, but rather `log n^2`, which is `O(log n)`.

Comment: @Thomas so you would still multiply as normal, even though there is a log function?

JuanLopes you're right! thanks.

Comment: The runtime for the third loop is neither `log^2 n` nor `O(log n)`. It doesn't contain `n` at all, but depends on `j`. It is then *not* clear that one just needs to multiply to get the full runtime (but may be so). Is this some homework question?

Comment: @m7thon yes it is. It doesn't contain `n`, however `j` depends on `n` right?

Comment: @Sarah well, yes, but only together with the outer loop. So the second and third loop together run `O(sum_{j=1}^n log j)`. Is this `O(n log n )`?

Comment: Yes I'd just multiply it. The first two loops have O(n * n) complexity since you're doing n * n iterations of the second loop. If you add the third loop you have n * n operations of approximately O(log(n)) complexity thus overall you get O(n * n* log(n) ).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First note that the outer loop is independent from the remaining two - it simply adds a `(n/4)*` multiplier. We will consider that later.

Now let's consider the complexity of

```
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    for ( int k = 1; k < j*j; k *= 2 )
```

We have the following sum:

0 + log<sub>2</sub>(1) + log<sub>2</sub>(2 * 2)  + ... + log<sub>2</sub>(n*n)

It is good to note that log<sub>2</sub>(n^2) = 2 * log<sub>2</sub>(n). Thus we re-factor the sum to:

2 * (0 + log<sub>2</sub>(1) + log<sub>2</sub>(2)  + ... + log<sub>2</sub>(n))

It is not very easy to analyze this sum but take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543634). Using Sterling's approximation one can that it is belongs to `O(n*log(n))`. Thus the overall complexity is `O((n/4)*2*n*log(n))= O(n^2*log(n))`

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. However, I'm not 100% on the calculation for the outer loop. Would you mind elaborating a little?

Comment: @SarahvdByl you mean the loop over `i`? It is independent from the other loops and executing it is equivalent to executing the inner loops `n/4` times.

Comment: No need for Stirling: log2(1) + log2(2) + ... + log2(n) <= log2(n) + log2(n) + ... + log2(n) = n*log2(n). This does not prove that the bound is tight, but for obtaining O(-) it's enough.

Comment: log(1)+log(2)+...+log(n)>=log([sqrt(n)])+log([sqrt(n)]+1)+...+log(n)>=(n-sqrt(n))(log n)/2=Omega(n log n), so tightness of the bound (up to multiplicative factors ignored in the O(...) notation anyway) does not need Stirling either.

Answer (score 7):

- In terms of `j`, the inner loop is `O(log_2(j^2))` time, but sine
  `log_2(j^2)=2log(j)`, it is actually `O(log(j))`.
- For each iteration of middle loop, it takes O(log(j)) time (to do the
  inner loop), so we need to sum:

  sum { log(j) | j=1,..., n-1 } log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n-1) = log((n-1)!)

And since `log((n-1)!)` is in `O((n-1)log(n-1)) = O(nlogn)`, we can conclude middle middle loop takes `O(nlogn)` operations .

- Note that both middle and inner loop are independent of `i`, so to
  get the total complexity, we can just multiply `n/4` (number of
  repeats of outer loop) with complexity of middle loop, and get:

  O(n/4 * nlogn) = O(n^2logn)

So, total complexity of this code is `O(n^2 * log(n))`

Comment: +1 I like the referring to the well-known `O(n*log(n)) = O(n!)`. One note - I think it is better to use operations instead of time e.g. `the inner loop performs O(log_2(j^2)) operations`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thanks for feedback. Editted.

Answer (score 4):

Time Complexity of a loop is considered as **O(n)** if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount (which is c in examples below):

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c) {
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Time complexity of nested loops is equal to the number of times the innermost statement is executed. For example the following sample loops have **O(n²)** time complexity:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += c) {
       for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += c) {
          // some O(1) expressions
       }
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i += c) {
       for (int j = i+1; j <=n; j += c) {
          // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Time Complexity of a loop is considered as **O(logn)** if the loop variables is divided / multiplied by a constant amount:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) {
       // some O(1) expressions
   }
   for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= c) {
       // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Now we have:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 4 ) <----- runs n times
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) <----- for every i again runs n times
        for ( int k = 1; k < j*j; k *= 2 )` <--- now for every j it runs logarithmic times.
```

So complexity is **O(n²logm)** where m is n² which can be simplified to **O(n²logn)** because `n²logm = n²logn² = n² * 2logn ~ n²logn`.

Comment: While it works here, multiplying complexities of "inner loop" with "outer loop" is not correct. Consider: `for (i=1; i < n; i*=2) for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`. Complexity of this code is NOT `Theta(nlogn)`. Doing it is a bad practice, ad it results in wrong answers in many cases.

Comment: In metaphor, it is similar to explaining 2+2+2=6 because there are **3** 2's and **2** +'s, and 3*2=6. This obviously fails for 3+3+3=6, since again - we have **3** 3's and **2** +'s.

Comment: @amit Thanks for clarifying.